# Subir imagen a servidor compartido laravel

Tags: laravel, imagen, carga

disculpen las molestias. Estoy hace varios días con la carga de una imagen y no logro mostrar la misma en la vista en el servidor compartido. En local todo funciona bien.

La imagen se guarda bien en la base de datos pero se me aloja en Storage/App/imagenes y comprendo que desde el servidor compartido esta ruta no es accesible.

Pero al querer cambiar la ruta no se guarda la imagen en public_html se guarda en la carpeta de laravel (sistema).

Mi código:

Componente

```
if($this->url){
        // $path = $this->url->store('public/imagenes');
        $nombreFoto = md5($this->url.microtime()).'.'.$this->url->extension();
        $this->url->storeAs('cargaImg', $nombreFoto);
    }

    Foto::create([
        'nombre' => $this->nombre,
        'detalle' => $this->detalle,
        'url' => $nombreFoto
    ]);
```

filesystem.php

```
'cargaImg' => [
      // public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
      // public_path('storage/photos') => storage_path('app/photos'),
       'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path().'imagenesCargada',
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public', 
    ],
```

La vita de carga

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" wire:model="url">
```

Probé utilizando store y funciona igual. También probé de agregar move de la siguiente manera

```
$nombre = time().'_'.$imagen->getClientOriginalName();

            $ruta = public_path('images/');

            $imagen->move($ruta, $nombre);
```

En cada cambio siempre use

```
    php artisan config:cache
    php artisan cache:clear
```

Recurro a ustedes por que no se que más podría hacer. Agradezco toda sugerencia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de luchar un rato encontré la solución, el problema era la carpeta PUBLIC_HTML lo solucione agregando en index.php

```
    $app->bind('path.public', function() {
      return __DIR__;
    });
```

Esto actualiza su ruta pública al directorio actual.
Si alguien necesita más info lo obtuve de aqui: https://dcblog.dev/laravel-55-change-public-to-public-html